# How to find common items across dictionaries where values can be lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries of varying size in a list which I want to find common items across.

Some of these dictionaries can have a list of dictionaries as some of the values.

**Order does not matter** so two sets of dictionary items are common regardless of order of keys. Two lists are common as long as the set of values are equal.

For instance, two dictionaries could look like.

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}

d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'f':4,'e':3}], 'g':4}
```

So common items here would be

```
common = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}
```

In the case of.

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}

d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'f':4,'e':3},{'c':1,'d':2}], 'g':4}
```

Since order does not matter, common items here would still be

```
common = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}
```

If the case would be

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':{'h':5}}]}

d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'f':4,'e':3}], 'g':4}
```

Then common items here would be

```
common = {'a' : 1}
```

Since the list of dictionaries are not identical.

In the case a key has a list of dictionaries as value, it is a common value between two dictionaries if the two lists are identical. But I can't out of the box use a string representation of the list because the order of the keys inside the dictionaries should not matter.

In the case of non list values I would simply do

```
 def extract_common_values(list_of_dictionaries):
     final_dict_items = list_of_dictionaries[0].items()
     for d in list_of_dictionaries[1:]:
         final_dict_items = final_dict_items & d.items()
return final_dict_items
```

But in my case now, it throws

```
    Cell In [12], line 18, in extract_common_values(list_of_dictionaries)
                       16 final_dict_items = list_of_dictionaries[0].items()
                       17 for d in list_of_dictionaries[1:]:
                  ---> 18     final_dict_items = final_dict_items & d.items()
                       19 return final_dict_items

                       TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What could be some way to solve this?

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: In what sense? Order in how the keys appear in the dictionary?

Comment: Key order, list order, anything that is ordered here~

Comment: No, it should not matter. A dictionary/list should be treated as equal to another dictionary/list as long as the content is the same, not the order. Thanks for clarifying. I'll add it to edit. [{'a':2},{'b':3}] should be common to [{'b':3},{'a':2}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def extract_common_values(d1, d2):
    common = {}
    for key in d1:
        v1 = d1[key]
        v2 = d2.get(key)
        if isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
            if all(x in v1 for x in v2) and all(x in v2 for x in v1):
                 common[key] = v1
        elif v1 == v2:
            common[key] = v1
    return common
```

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}
d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'f':4,'e':3}], 'g':4}
print(extract_common_values(d1, d2))

# Output:
{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': 1, 'd': 2}, {'e': 3, 'f': 4}]}
```

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':4}]}
d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'f':4,'e':3},{'c':1,'d':2}], 'g':4}
print(extract_common_values(d1, d2))

# Output:
{'a' :{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': 1, 'd': 2}, {'e': 3, 'f': 4}]}
```

```
d1 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'e':3,'f':{'h':5}}]}
d2 = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : [{'c':1,'d':2},{'f':4,'e':3}], 'g':4}
print(extract_common_values(d1, d2))

# Output:
{'a': 1}
```